# Unable to update Maven Project from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-2

I was trying to check for new updates in Eclipse Kepler and saw below error message

Unable to read repository at https://otto.takari.io/content/sites/m2e.extras/m2eclipse-mavenarchiver/0.17.0/N/LATEST/content.xml.

sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Answer (score 0):

That is not an eclipse issue nor a maven issue. Java tries to verify the Certificate chain, but fails for some reason. The cause might be:

- Proxy and/or other security appliances; especially if you're stuck in a company network
- https connection is forbidden
- the target site uses a self signed certifcate

[See this SO answer for solutions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore)